# Optimizing Google Apps Script that runs a loop over 900 rows

Tags: loops, google-apps-script

I can provide more background on my project (if necessary) but here is the bottom line.

I have a spreadsheet with over 900 line items that need to be processed.  Each line item needs to go through 2-6 different team members to be processed (depending on the type of item, so some may be 2 people and some may be all 6 people).  I am trying to create metrics on how long each line item is with each team member.

On the second tab of the spreadsheet, I have listed out all 900 line items again and this is where I intend to keep track of the status and the timestamp of when it moves to the next status. From there I can do some analysis to see how long it takes each line item to move from one status to the next.

I wrote a script to look at both tabs and match the line items on the primary key (the initial timestamp) and look at the status each line is in on my main spreadsheet and compare it to what status is logged in my metrics tab.  If it's a different status then my script will log the new status and timestamp the new status.

My script works but it's incredibly slow and I can only get through about 50 lines before it reaches maximum time execution.  **I just need help making the script more efficient so that it can get through all 900 lines in a single execution.**

```
function myFunction() {
var app = UiApp.createApplication()

var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1ijBVLZcGlvxvB9R_r2wXZUylIem70yihZpqDLufNm9Q');
var newS = doc.getSheetByName('NEW')
var metricsS = doc.getSheetByName('Metrics Data')
var numRows = metricsS.getDataRange().getNumRows()

for (var j = 2; j < numRows ; j++) {
for (var i = 2; i < numRows ; i++) {                
  if(((metricsS.getRange(j, 1, 1, metricsS.getLastColumn()).getCell(1, 1).getValue()) == (newS.getDataRange().getCell(i, 1).getValue())) && ((metricsS.getRange(j, 1, 1, ((metricsS.getRange(j, 1, 1, 100).getValues())[0].filter(String).length)).getCell(1, ((metricsS.getRange(j, 1, 1, 100).getValues())[0].filter(String).length)-1).getValue()) != (newS.getDataRange().getCell(i, 2).getValue()))) {     
metricsS.getRange(j, 1, 1, 250).getCell(1, ((metricsS.getRange(j, 1, 1, 100).getValues())[0].filter(String).length)+1).setValue(newS.getDataRange().getCell(i, 2).getValue());    
metricsS.getRange(j, 1, 1, 100).getCell(1, ((metricsS.getRange(j, 1, 1, 100).getValues())[0].filter(String).length)+1).setValue(new Date()); break;}}
}

return app;}
```

Comment: Every getRange() call is taking a lot of time.  You are best served getting all the data into an Object for each tab (sheet) and then lopping through one of the objects.  See how that is done in the article [Tutorial: Simple Mail Merge](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/mail_merge) Espcially the sample code at the bottom of the article, from the getRowsData() function to the end.

Answer (score 3):

The standard advice is to not use getValue in a loop: [use batch operation getValues instead](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/best_practices#use-batch-operations). In your case, this would be

```
var allData = metricsS.getDataRange().getValues();

// now we have all data, so loop through this JavaScript array

for (var j = 1; j < allData.length ; j++) {
  for (var i = 1; i < allData.length ; i++) { 
    if (allData[i][2] > allData[j][0]) {  // some condition
      // do something
    }          
  }
}
```

Just keep in mind that while row/column numbers begin with 1, JavaScript indices begin with 0. Hence, looping over all rows starting with 2nd means starting the loop with index 1, as above.

Similarly with `setValue`: place whatever output you have into a double JavaScript array, and then apply `setValues` once, after the loop finished.